# How to maintain data after DbSet.Remove?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I use a repository pattern and to make things centralized I created a IValidate interface that each of my repositories can implement. In that I make entity validations depending on their state. So far so good, until I removed an entity. When I tried to access a property from a removed entity I got an exception, the entity was no longer in context.

Ex:

```
class A
{
   int MyClassBId
   B MyClassB
}
```

If I add or update entity `A` I can access `A.MyClassB` with no hassle. But if I delete (DbSet.Remove) even before calling SaveChanges (my approach of course calls this Validations before save) the references are null. So if I try to access `A.MyClassB` again I get null reference, but the "not lazy-loaded" objects are there. For instance, `A.MyClassBId` still has the FK for `B`.

I understood that DbSet.Remove only marked the entity for deletion, nothing else. Does it also remove it from context? How can I solve this? Call DbSet.Remove and still maintain the references in the object, at least until SaveChanges is called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that two processes are going on:

1. Entity Framework keeps track of the entities that are loaded in `DbContext`, maintaining their state as `Added`, `Modified`, `Deleted` or `Unchanged`. You can check this with a `MyDataContext.Entry(MyEntity).State`call.
2. Outwardly the POCO classes behave just like you would expect from classes that have no connection to an ORM whatsoever.

So what happens when you call the DbSet.Remove method is that the entity will be marked for deletion under the covers and outwardly it will be removed from the ICollection that it belonged too.

If you want to keep track of entities that should be deleted on a `SaveChanges` call you will have to define a `WillBeDeleted` property on the entity and your code will have to take this property into account when counting active entities, validation, etc. The actual `DbSet.Remove` call should then be made just before calling `SaveChanges`.

Alternatively, you can use `MyDataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled=False` before initialising the DbContext. Now the Entity that  is subjected to the `DbSet.Remove` method will not be deleted from its `ICollection` in the POCO class, but you have no way of knowing that the entity is meant to be deleted without again tracking this in a property of your own.

Comment: I thought about that approach of adding a property on each POCO class, but that seemed somewhat expensive. Am I wrong? About the second suggestion, if I set that I'd also need the extra property and I wouldn't like to stop EF from tracking changes. Waiting for your reply. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It would only be somewhat expensive if the new `WillBeDeleted` property makes it into the database, which is unnecessary. You can prevent that by annotating the property as `<NotMapped>`. The cost comes with having to take into account the `WillBeDeleted` property in every enumeration or count you make of the entity. I at least have seen no way around that and have had to fix numerous bugs because of it, but we have implemented it.

Comment: About stopping EF from tracking changes: this is *quite* a good idea in many scenarios as it can improve performance, but I agree that disabling it by default is unwise.

Comment: Ok, Dabblernl, I'm going with that then... I have some unwanted changes to perform on my code, if you'd excuse me :D Thanks again.